# X ∼ Exp(1) and Y ∼ uniform(0, 1) are independent. Compute $E(e^{-XY^2})$.

Tags: probability, expected-value, uniform-distribution, exponential-distribution

X ∼ Exp(1) and Y ∼ uniform(0, 1) are independent. Compute $E(e^{-XY^2})$.

I am having trouble answering this question, I am not sure if I should take advantage of moment generating functions or multivariable LOTUS. I think multivariable law of the unconscious statistician would be easier, but I am unsure on how to derive the joint pdf.Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: You should add \$ symbols to the start and end of your math to make it more legible, and put braces {} around your exponents.  Formatting help is [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)

Comment: @RobertTheTutor thank you, just edited it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alternatively, use moment-generating functions.  We have
$$\operatorname{E}[e^{-XY^2}] = \operatorname{E}[\operatorname{E}[e^{-XY^2} \mid Y]] = \operatorname{E}[M_X(-Y^2)] = \operatorname{E}\left[\frac{1}{1-(-Y^2)}\right] = \int_{y=0}^1 \frac{dy}{1+y^2} = \tan^{-1} 1 = \frac{\pi}{4},$$ where the MGF of $X$ is $M_X(t) = \operatorname{E}[e^{tX}] = \frac{1}{1-t}$.

Comment: thank you so much! this was the method I was talking about

Answer (score 1):

We have
\begin{align*}
\mathbb E[e^{-XY^2}] &=\int_0^1\int_0^\infty e^{-xu^2} e^{-x} dx du\\
& = \int_0^1 \Big(-\frac{1}{1+u^2} e^{-(1+u^2)x} \vert_{x=0}^\infty \Big) du\\
&=\int_0^1\frac{1}{1+u^2} du = {\rm arctan}(1) - {\rm arctan}(0)= \frac{\pi}{4},
\end{align*}
since ${\rm arctan}’(x) = 1/(1+x^2).$ Here in the first line I am using the fact that the joint density of $X$ and $Y$ is:
$$
f_{X,Y}(x,u)=e^{-x}1_{x>0}1_{u\in(0,1)}.
$$

Comment: Stillian, can you explain why the exponent is like the way you wrote it?

Comment: Fixed some typos and added an explanation. Thanks Fabio.

Answer (score -1):

If $X$ and $Y$ are independent with respective densities $f$ and $g$, then for any reasonable function $F$,

$$E[F(X,Y)] = \iint F(x,y)f(x)g(y) dxdy.$$

Do you know the densities of $X$ and $Y$ in this case?

Comment: the density of X would be $(\lamda) e^{-\lambda x}$ , the desntiy of Y would be 1 when 0 < x < 1, 0 otherwise, im just having trouble setting up the double integral

Comment: You'e basically there - in this case, $\lambda = 1$, and $F(x,y) = e^{-xy^2}$.